# How to optimize the following double for loop in octave?

Tags: performance, optimization, for-loop, octave

I have the following code in octave:

```
dist=0;
for i = 1:length(x);        
    for j = 1:length(y);
        v  = x(i,:) - y(j,:);
        distvect(j) = norm(v);
    endfor 
    dist = dist + min(distvect);
endfor
```

where x and y are matrices with size n x 2 and m x 2. My main problem: I need to run the code above several times.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to optimize it with using probably just one matrix instead of the v vector each time in the inner for loop, but I could not find it. I searched online, I found an [arrayfun](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Application.html) function, which might help, but I could not figure out how to use.

Thanks for helping,
grus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best optimization you can make in this case is to implement the `norm` yourself to take advantage of matrix multiplications, rather than looping over the individual elements.

Recall that, for vector values, `norm(v)` calculates `norm(v, 2)`, which is the Euclidean distance

```
norm(v, 2) = (sum (abs (v) .^ 2)) ^ (1/2)
```

Since you only need to find the minimum distance, you do not actually need to take the square root until later.  For compactness, let `a = x(i, :)`, `b = y(j, :)`, `M = length(x)` and `N = length(y)`. Since your variable `v` contains a vector of differences, we can expand the calculation of `distvect` into

```
distvect   = norm(v)
           = norm(x(i, :) - y(j, :))
           = norm(a - b)
           = (sum (abs( a - b ) .^ 2)) ^ (1/2)
distvect^2 = sum (abs ( a - b ) .^ 2)
```

Now, expand the quadratic term, `(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2`, which makes the `abs` function redundant

```
distvect^2 = sum (sum(a.*a) * ones(1,N) - 2*a*b' + ones(M,1) * sum(b'.*b') )
```

The final optimization, it to apply the function across multiple values.  This is done by using the outer product of your `x` and `y` matrices to create a `length(x)` by `length(y)` matrix.  Then just take the minimum distance along each column and sum the square root of the results

```
xx   = sum(x .* x, 2) * ones(1, length(y))
xy   = x * y'
yy   = ones(length(x), 1) * sum(y' .* y')

dist = sum(sqrt(min(xx - 2.*xy + yy)))
```

Comment: I think there's some errors. try this with x=rand(440,2), y=rand(740,2);

Comment: Thanks, I think it's fixed now.  I was summing over the wrong axis.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for, it is much faster this way.